# pgfplotstable: read and manipulate multiple data files into one tabular

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

When trying to typeset a datatable I can't insert

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset
```

in a tabular environment.
What am I missing?

---

mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}                                           
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\begin{document}                                                           

\begin{tabular}{c}                                                         
\pgfplotstabletypeset{                                                     
a b                                                                        
1 2                                                                        
3 4                                                                        
}                                                                          
\end{tabular}                                                              
\end{document}
```

which yields (pdflatex)

```
Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 12.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.12     }
```

---

Alternatively, I'd like to know how to efficently typeset the following table (which was made with google docs and is not completely filled with data since I was planning to typeset it with latex)

[image: final table],

whose data is contained in 28 different .txt files (one for each row-column combination) with 10 lines in each one, no heading or whatsoever, as this one containing the data  of the first row and column

```
0.6545
0.6515
0.6547
0.6561
0.6524
0.6533
0.6521
0.6497
0.6490
0.6540
```

that should be "broken" in two columns in the final table (and the order of the data DOES matter).

I already know how to compose it manually (via some vim magic), and this particular case it is in fact feasible, but I am interested in the automation of the process, with an arbitrary number of columns (preferably using pgfplotstable).

Thanks in advance to all TeX superheroes out there :)

Comment: The `\pgfplotstabletypeset` comand generates the complete `tabular` code, so you don't need to call it inside a `tabular` environment.

Comment: @Jake I'm already aware of that, but I wanted to insert the data in a more complex tabular, as in the image below, and doing so seemed the best solution for me. I'm open to different solutions

Comment: *'a different file formatted like this'* can you give us a lot more detail please? For example is this a CSV file where each column has a heading or is it another type of file? The answer depends upon this information :-)

Comment: @cmhughes I updated the question to include more info, hope it's clear now

Comment: Great! See what you think of my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that uses the [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplotstable.pdf) package, combined with [`booktabs`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/booktabs/booktabs.pdf), [`siunitx`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) (for decimal alignment) and [`multirow`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/multirow/multirow.pdf) (for `multirow`s in a `tabular`).

First of all, the output:

[image]

I've assumed that each of your 28 data files has 10 rows (as described in your question) and is named

```
data11.txt  data12.txt  data13.txt data14.txt
data21.txt  data22.txt  data23.txt data24.txt
  ................
  ................
  ................
data71.txt  data72.txt  data73.txt data74.txt
```

You didn't specify a naming convention in your question.

The main algorithm is as follows:

- for each column

  - read the first data file (as is) into `firstColumn`
  - read rows 5--10 from the first data file into `secondColumn`
  - read rows 5--10 *again* from the first data file into `secondColumn`
  - repeat the process for each row file (`data21.txt`, `data31.txt`, etc)

When it comes to typesetting the table, the duplicated rows need to be skipped, hence the:

```
skip rows between index={5}{10},
 skip rows between index={15}{20},
 skip rows between index={25}{30},
 skip rows between index={35}{40},
 skip rows between index={45}{50},
 skip rows between index={55}{60},
 skip rows between index={65}{70},
```

The `multirow` magic borrows from [pgfplotstable-with-multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213765/pgfplotstable-with-multirow)

Here are two copies of the code: one assumes that you already have the data files, the other does not. The difference is that the version that creates the files uses the `filecontents` package, which creates some cruft in the header of the `data` files; this changes (very slightly) the reading of the data files.

References:

- [pgfplotstable-without-headings-row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67542/pgfplotstable-without-headings-row)
- [multiple-files-input-to-one-pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10284/multiple-files-input-to-one-pgfplotstable)
- [pgfplotstable-with-multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213765/pgfplotstable-with-multirow)

## Code (version assuming you have data.*.txt)

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

% create a master tabular, which will store the almagamated tabular
\pgfplotstablenew{70}{\masterTabular}

% loop through the columns
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4}{
 % read first file in each column separately
 % first column read everything
 \pgfplotstableread{data1#1.txt}\firstColumn
 % second column read only the second 5 entries
 \pgfplotstableread[skip first n=5]{data1#1.txt}\secondColumn
 % then duplicate them to make the columns match in size
 \pgfplotstablevertcat{\secondColumn}{\secondColumn}
 % now loop through the remaining rows in the column
 \pgfplotsforeachungrouped\myRowIndex in {2,...,7}{
  \pgfplotstableread{data\myRowIndex#1.txt}\dataB
  \pgfplotstablevertcat{\firstColumn}{\dataB}
  % second column
  \pgfplotstableread[skip first n=5]{data\myRowIndex#1.txt}\dataD
  \pgfplotstablevertcat{\dataD}{\dataD}
  \pgfplotstablevertcat{\secondColumn}{\dataD}
 }
 % first column into master tabular
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\firstColumn}{[index]0}]{par1#1}{\masterTabular}
 % second column into master tabular
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\secondColumn}{[index]0}]{par2#1}{\masterTabular}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
 % header row
 every head row/.style={
  output empty row, % hide column names
  before row={\toprule%
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Zero}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{{One}}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Two}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Three}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Four}\\
  },
  after row={\midrule},
 },
 % every 5th row in the body
 every nth row={5[-1]}{after row=\midrule},
 % last row
 every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
 % column types
 display columns/0/.style={
  assign cell content/.code={%
   % the multirow bit
   \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(int(\pgfplotstablerow/10)==\pgfplotstablerow/10,int(\pgfplotstablerow/10),-1)}%
   \ifcase\pgfmathresult% rows 0--5
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 1}}%
   \or% rows 6--10
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 2}}%
   \or% rows 11--15
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 3}}%
   \or% rows 16--20
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 4}}%
   \or% rows 21--25
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 5}}%
   \or% rows 26--30
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 6}}%
   \or% rows 31--35
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 7}}%
   \else% do nothing!
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%%Do nothing
   \fi
  },
 },
 display columns/1/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/2/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/3/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/4/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/5/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/6/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/7/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/8/.style={string type,column type=S},
 % skip these rows, which have been read by pgfplotstableread above
 skip rows between index={5}{10},
 skip rows between index={15}{20},
 skip rows between index={25}{30},
 skip rows between index={35}{40},
 skip rows between index={45}{50},
 skip rows between index={55}{60},
 skip rows between index={65}{70},
]{\masterTabular}

\end{document}
```

## Code (version assuming you do not have data.*.txt)

*Note: this version creates the 28 different files, data11.txt,..., data74.txt and uses `skip first n=9` to account for the extra cruft from the `filecontents` output*

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data11.txt}
11.1
11.2
11.3
11.4
11.5
11.6
11.7
11.8
11.9
11.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data21.txt}
21.1
21.2
21.3
21.4
21.5
21.6
21.7
21.8
21.9
21.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data31.txt}
31.1
31.2
31.3
31.4
31.5
31.6
31.7
31.8
31.9
31.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data41.txt}
41.1
41.2
41.3
41.4
41.5
41.6
41.7
41.8
41.9
41.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data51.txt}
51.1
51.2
51.3
51.4
51.5
51.6
51.7
51.8
51.9
51.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data61.txt}
61.1
61.2
61.3
61.4
61.5
61.6
61.7
61.8
61.9
61.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data71.txt}
71.1
71.2
71.3
71.4
71.5
71.6
71.7
71.8
71.9
71.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data12.txt}
12.1
12.2
12.3
12.4
12.5
12.6
12.7
12.8
12.9
12.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data22.txt}
22.1
22.2
22.3
22.4
22.5
22.6
22.7
22.8
22.9
22.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data32.txt}
32.1
32.2
32.3
32.4
32.5
32.6
32.7
32.8
32.9
32.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data42.txt}
42.1
42.2
42.3
42.4
42.5
42.6
42.7
42.8
42.9
42.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data52.txt}
52.1
52.2
52.3
52.4
52.5
52.6
52.7
52.8
52.9
52.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data62.txt}
62.1
62.2
62.3
62.4
62.5
62.6
62.7
62.8
62.9
62.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data72.txt}
72.1
72.2
72.3
72.4
72.5
72.6
72.7
72.8
72.9
72.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data13.txt}
13.1
13.2
13.3
13.4
13.5
13.6
13.7
13.8
13.9
13.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data23.txt}
23.1
23.2
23.3
23.4
23.5
23.6
23.7
23.8
23.9
23.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data33.txt}
33.1
33.2
33.3
33.4
33.5
33.6
33.7
33.8
33.9
33.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data43.txt}
43.1
43.2
43.3
43.4
43.5
43.6
43.7
43.8
43.9
43.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data53.txt}
53.1
53.2
53.3
53.4
53.5
53.6
53.7
53.8
53.9
53.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data63.txt}
63.1
63.2
63.3
63.4
63.5
63.6
63.7
63.8
63.9
63.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data73.txt}
73.1
73.2
73.3
73.4
73.5
73.6
73.7
73.8
73.9
73.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data14.txt}
14.1
14.2
14.3
14.4
14.5
14.6
14.7
14.8
14.9
14.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data24.txt}
24.1
24.2
24.3
24.4
24.5
24.6
24.7
24.8
24.9
24.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data34.txt}
34.1
34.2
34.3
34.4
34.5
34.6
34.7
34.8
34.9
34.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data44.txt}
44.1
44.2
44.3
44.4
44.5
44.6
44.7
44.8
44.9
44.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data54.txt}
54.1
54.2
54.3
54.4
54.5
54.6
54.7
54.8
54.9
54.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data64.txt}
64.1
64.2
64.3
64.4
64.5
64.6
64.7
64.8
64.9
64.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data74.txt}
74.1
74.2
74.3
74.4
74.5
74.6
74.7
74.8
74.9
74.10
\end{filecontents}

% create a master tabular, which will store the almagamated tabular
\pgfplotstablenew{70}{\masterTabular}

% loop through the columns
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4}{
 % read first file in each column separately
 % first column read everything
 \pgfplotstableread{data1#1.txt}\firstColumn
 % second column read only the second 5 entries
 \pgfplotstableread[skip first n=9]{data1#1.txt}\secondColumn
 % then duplicate them to make the columns match in size
 \pgfplotstablevertcat{\secondColumn}{\secondColumn}
 % now loop through the remaining rows in the column
 \pgfplotsforeachungrouped\myRowIndex in {2,...,7}{
  \pgfplotstableread{data\myRowIndex#1.txt}\dataB
  \pgfplotstablevertcat{\firstColumn}{\dataB}
  % second column
  \pgfplotstableread[skip first n=9]{data\myRowIndex#1.txt}\dataD
  \pgfplotstablevertcat{\dataD}{\dataD}
  \pgfplotstablevertcat{\secondColumn}{\dataD}
 }
 % first column into master tabular
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\firstColumn}{[index]0}]{par1#1}{\masterTabular}
 % second column into master tabular
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\secondColumn}{[index]0}]{par2#1}{\masterTabular}
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
 % header row
 every head row/.style={
  output empty row, % hide column names
  before row={\toprule%
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Zero}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{{One}}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Two}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Three}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Four}\\
  },
  after row={\midrule},
 },
 % every 5th row in the body
 every nth row={5[-1]}{after row=\midrule},
 % last row
 every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
 % column types
 display columns/0/.style={
  assign cell content/.code={%
   % the multirow bit
   \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(int(\pgfplotstablerow/10)==\pgfplotstablerow/10,int(\pgfplotstablerow/10),-1)}%
   \ifcase\pgfmathresult% rows 0--5
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 1}}%
   \or% rows 6--10
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 2}}%
   \or% rows 11--15
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 3}}%
   \or% rows 16--20
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 4}}%
   \or% rows 21--25
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 5}}%
   \or% rows 26--30
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 6}}%
   \or% rows 31--35
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 7}}%
   \else% do nothing!
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%%Do nothing
   \fi
  },
 },
 display columns/1/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/2/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/3/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/4/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/5/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/6/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/7/.style={string type,column type=S},
 display columns/8/.style={string type,column type=S},
 % skip these rows, which have been read by pgfplotstableread above
 skip rows between index={5}{10},
 skip rows between index={15}{20},
 skip rows between index={25}{30},
 skip rows between index={35}{40},
 skip rows between index={45}{50},
 skip rows between index={55}{60},
 skip rows between index={65}{70},
]{\masterTabular}

\end{document}
```

## Comment

You might like to try

```
every nth row={5[-1]}{after row=\cmidrule{2-9}},
```

which gives

[image]

## Final comment

Thanks to @percusse and his answer to [text-size-in-pgfplotstable-tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127432/text-size-in-pgfplotstable-tables) you can use

```
\pgfplotstableset{
    my siunitx column/.style={%
        /pgfplots/table/display columns/#1/.style={%
            string type,column type=S,
        }
    }
}
```

which allows you to use

```
% columns 1 through 8 are siunitx
my siunitx column/.list={1,...,8},
```

here's a complete code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data11.txt}
11.1
11.2
11.3
11.4
11.5
11.6
11.7
11.8
11.9
11.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data21.txt}
21.1
21.2
21.3
21.4
21.5
21.6
21.7
21.8
21.9
21.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data31.txt}
31.1
31.2
31.3
31.4
31.5
31.6
31.7
31.8
31.9
31.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data41.txt}
41.1
41.2
41.3
41.4
41.5
41.6
41.7
41.8
41.9
41.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data51.txt}
51.1
51.2
51.3
51.4
51.5
51.6
51.7
51.8
51.9
51.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data61.txt}
61.1
61.2
61.3
61.4
61.5
61.6
61.7
61.8
61.9
61.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data71.txt}
71.1
71.2
71.3
71.4
71.5
71.6
71.7
71.8
71.9
71.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data12.txt}
12.1
12.2
12.3
12.4
12.5
12.6
12.7
12.8
12.9
12.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data22.txt}
22.1
22.2
22.3
22.4
22.5
22.6
22.7
22.8
22.9
22.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data32.txt}
32.1
32.2
32.3
32.4
32.5
32.6
32.7
32.8
32.9
32.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data42.txt}
42.1
42.2
42.3
42.4
42.5
42.6
42.7
42.8
42.9
42.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data52.txt}
52.1
52.2
52.3
52.4
52.5
52.6
52.7
52.8
52.9
52.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data62.txt}
62.1
62.2
62.3
62.4
62.5
62.6
62.7
62.8
62.9
62.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data72.txt}
72.1
72.2
72.3
72.4
72.5
72.6
72.7
72.8
72.9
72.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data13.txt}
13.1
13.2
13.3
13.4
13.5
13.6
13.7
13.8
13.9
13.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data23.txt}
23.1
23.2
23.3
23.4
23.5
23.6
23.7
23.8
23.9
23.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data33.txt}
33.1
33.2
33.3
33.4
33.5
33.6
33.7
33.8
33.9
33.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data43.txt}
43.1
43.2
43.3
43.4
43.5
43.6
43.7
43.8
43.9
43.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data53.txt}
53.1
53.2
53.3
53.4
53.5
53.6
53.7
53.8
53.9
53.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data63.txt}
63.1
63.2
63.3
63.4
63.5
63.6
63.7
63.8
63.9
63.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data73.txt}
73.1
73.2
73.3
73.4
73.5
73.6
73.7
73.8
73.9
73.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data14.txt}
14.1
14.2
14.3
14.4
14.5
14.6
14.7
14.8
14.9
14.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data24.txt}
24.1
24.2
24.3
24.4
24.5
24.6
24.7
24.8
24.9
24.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data34.txt}
34.1
34.2
34.3
34.4
34.5
34.6
34.7
34.8
34.9
34.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data44.txt}
44.1
44.2
44.3
44.4
44.5
44.6
44.7
44.8
44.9
44.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data54.txt}
54.1
54.2
54.3
54.4
54.5
54.6
54.7
54.8
54.9
54.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data64.txt}
64.1
64.2
64.3
64.4
64.5
64.6
64.7
64.8
64.9
64.10
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data74.txt}
74.1
74.2
74.3
74.4
74.5
74.6
74.7
74.8
74.9
74.10
\end{filecontents}

% create a master tabular, which will store the almagamated tabular
\pgfplotstablenew{70}{\masterTabular}

% loop through the columns
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4}{
 % read first file in each column separately
 % first column read everything
 \pgfplotstableread{data1#1.txt}\firstColumn
 % second column read only the second 5 entries
 \pgfplotstableread[skip first n=9]{data1#1.txt}\secondColumn
 % then duplicate them to make the columns match in size
 \pgfplotstablevertcat{\secondColumn}{\secondColumn}
 % now loop through the remaining rows in the column
 \pgfplotsforeachungrouped\myRowIndex in {2,...,7}{
  \pgfplotstableread{data\myRowIndex#1.txt}\dataB
  \pgfplotstablevertcat{\firstColumn}{\dataB}
  % second column
  \pgfplotstableread[skip first n=9]{data\myRowIndex#1.txt}\dataD
  \pgfplotstablevertcat{\dataD}{\dataD}
  \pgfplotstablevertcat{\secondColumn}{\dataD}
 }
 % first column into master tabular
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\firstColumn}{[index]0}]{par1#1}{\masterTabular}
 % second column into master tabular
 \pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\secondColumn}{[index]0}]{par2#1}{\masterTabular}
}

% slightly reduce repetition of column styles
\pgfplotstableset{
    my siunitx column/.style={%
        /pgfplots/table/display columns/#1/.style={%
            string type,column type=S,
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
 % header row
 every head row/.style={
  output empty row, % hide column names
  before row={\toprule%
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Zero}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{{One}}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Two}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Three}&
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Four}\\
  },
  after row={\midrule},
 },
 % every 5th row in the body
 every nth row={5[-1]}{after row=\cmidrule{2-9}},
 % last row
 every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
 % column types
 display columns/0/.style={
  assign cell content/.code={%
   % the multirow bit
   \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(int(\pgfplotstablerow/10)==\pgfplotstablerow/10,int(\pgfplotstablerow/10),-1)}%
   \ifcase\pgfmathresult% rows 0--5
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 1}}%
   \or% rows 6--10
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 2}}%
   \or% rows 11--15
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 3}}%
   \or% rows 16--20
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 4}}%
   \or% rows 21--25
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 5}}%
   \or% rows 26--30
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 6}}%
   \or% rows 31--35
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
    {\multirow{5}{*}{Case 7}}%
   \else% do nothing!
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%%Do nothing
   \fi
  },
 },
 % columns 1 through 8 are siunitx
 my siunitx column/.list={1,...,8},
 % skip these rows, which have been read by pgfplotstableread above
 skip rows between index={5}{10},
 skip rows between index={15}{20},
 skip rows between index={25}{30},
 skip rows between index={35}{40},
 skip rows between index={45}{50},
 skip rows between index={55}{60},
 skip rows between index={65}{70},
]{\masterTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: an example of `/.list` usage ;) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127432/text-size-in-pgfplotstable-tables

Comment: @percusse thanks for the link :) are you thinking that would reduce some of the multirow stuff?

Comment: Haha no I mean you can reduce the number of repeating styles